# Calculate leftover volume of a drilled out cube

Tags: integration, geometry

Say you have a cube with sidelengths $2r$, now you use a cylindrical drill with radius $r$ to hollow out the cube along the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes through the middle of the cube so that you're left with something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz2Nn.png), meaning we're left with the 8 corners of the cube which each resemble some kind of [spike-like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkdV1.png) structure. I want to calculate the total volume $V$ of the leftover spikes.

Since this is a symmetric problem we can calculate the volume $V_{spike}$ of 1 spike and multiply with 8 to get the full volume.

Now, I can set up an integral and calculate the volume of 1 spike if we only use 1 drill (the area under a circle), just to simplify things at the start (using the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469820/area-under-quarter-circle-by-integration)):

$$V_{spike\_1\_drill}=r^3 - r\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2} dx$$
$$V_{spike\_1\_drill}=r^3\left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

And then I get stuck when trying to add another drill, I just can't visualize how to set up the remaining integration functions and limits such that it interacts properly with what I already have up above. I don't know if it would be a better approach to calculate the volume of the drilled out volume instead, but then you still have the problem of layering things correctly so you don't include any overlaps.

Any help/hints is appreciated.

Comment: Is the drill a cone? What is its height?

Comment: The drill is a cylinder passing through the middle of the cube through the flat faces, edited the OP.

Comment: I would suggest putting the center at the origin and using symmetry to the fullest extent. Look at the portion in the first octant with $0\le y\le x$ and $0\le z\le x$. Probably a convenient choice of coordinates might be better than $xyz$.

Comment: Hint: the solid has the volume of a cube minus the volume of a Steinmetz solid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid#Tricylinder

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. However there is a distinct difference between the negative space left behind by the drills and the similar Steinmetz solid, in that the drills act like an OR gate when combining the volume, while the Steinmetz solid looks to act like an AND gate. So the combined volume taken out by the drills looks like: [link](https://i.imgur.com/lPNj55s.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Ted Shifrin in comments, place the center of the cube at the origin with its faces parallel to coordinate planes.

[image]

Then the equation of drills' cylindrical surfaces are,

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
$y^2 + z^2 = r^2$
$z^2 + x^2 = r^2$

Now take example of the left-out piece of solid on the right bottom corner (corner $2$) -

If you see the face shaded in dark blue and dark grey (corner $2$), that is to the right of $x^2 + z^2 = r^2$. Now at the intersection of other two cylinders,

$x^2 + y^2 = y^2 + z^2 = r^2 \implies x = \pm z$. As it's corner $2$, $x = - z$

So for $x \leq - z$, $y$ is bound below by the surface shaded in dark blue and above by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.

Now at the intersection of $x = -z$ and $x^2 + z^2 = r^2, z = \pm \frac {r}{\sqrt2}$. As it's corner $2$, $z = - \frac{r}{\sqrt2}$

That leads to the bounds,

$-r \leq y \leq - \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$
$\sqrt{r^2 - z^2} \leq x \leq - z$
$- r \leq z \leq - \frac{r}{\sqrt2}$

for the order of integration $dy ~ dx ~ dz$.

For $x \geq - z, $ you will have the same volume and then there are $8$ such corners.

So once you evaluate the integral, multiply by $16$.

---

Given your quest for further clarity on bounds, let me provide a bit more detail. The upper bound of $z$ is $ - \frac {r}{\sqrt2}$ because we divided the volume of corner $2$ into two. We did so because *we did not have a single bound of $y$ for the whole face of corner 2 which is in the plane $y = -r$*. For $x \leq - z$, $y$ is bound above by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and for $x \geq -z$, $y$ is bound above by the cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$. The bounds that I wrote in my answer above is for the part shaded in dark blue. For the part above plane $x = -z$ (shaded in dark grey), the bounds will be -

$- r \leq y \leq - \sqrt{r^2-z^2}$
$- x \leq z - \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$
$\frac{r}{\sqrt2} \leq x \leq r$

for the order of integration $dy ~ dz ~ dx$. But the volume is same by symmetry so you can just evaluate the first integral I originally wrote and multiply it by $2$ to find the volume of corner $2$. Then multiply by $8$ for $8$ corners.

To further show what's going on, let me take corner $4$.

The surface marked in yellow is part of cube drilled by $x^2 + z^2 = r^2$; the part marked in light blue is by the drill $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and the part marked in green is by the drill $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$. As you can see, the plane $z = x$ is the intersection of drills $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ and should be used to split the volume integral to get right bounds of $y$ for the face of  corner $4$, which is in the plane $y = r$.

Comment: Alright I can make sense of this some of the way, you're ordering your integration and limits such that integrating y introduces $x$ and integrating $x$ introduces $z$, and I can see how the integration limits for $y$ and $x$ are bounds for the spike geometry.

However the z limits confuses me, why the $z\le-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$? My intuition wants that upper bound to be 0. For me there is an issue in that there are 3 surface "pairs" lets call them, a cylinder cut and an outer surface of the cube. The $y$ and $x$ operations both take care of two of these, but the $z$ integration doesn't?

Comment: @Jens please see modified diagram and more details on bounds. Request you to read through the whole answer. It is a bit involving but should help clarify your questions on bounds. Feel free to ask if any further clarifications required.

Answer (score 2):

From your picture, we can actually break each corner further into half, and multiply the following set up by $16$

$$V = 16\int_{\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}}^r\int_{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^x\int_{-r}^{-\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$

This integral gives the correct answer, but I can't calculate properly. @Intelligenti has the proper calculation from Mathematica as

$$2(4+4\sqrt{2}-3\pi)r^3$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should say that I can check the volume via SolidWorks from where I got the images in the OP, and it reports a total leftover volume of $V\approx0.77$ when $r=1$, whereas your result gives $V(r=1)=6.109$.
It also seems counterintuitive that your result scales linearly with $r$, shouldn't it scale according to $r^3$?

Comment: I checked a couple more design points for $r$ [here](https://i.imgur.com/2Op72z5.png) ($V$ being total volume for all spikes reported by SolidWorks). Interestingly the $r=1$ result just happens to coincide with being 8 times that of the other, but it does seem to scale up quite quickly as $r$ gets larger instead of acting linearly.

Comment: I computed your integral with Mathematica, here's the result: $$4 \left(\pi -2 \sqrt{2}\right) r^3.$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I realized the original integral had the wrong bounds because I pictured the location of the corner incorrectly. It should now be right

Comment: @Jens does this formula now work? I had the lower bound for $z$ incorrect initially

Comment: @Ninad There is still a discrepancy between what SolidWorks reports and the result in your updated answer: [link](https://i.imgur.com/zBC4gIO.png) (added Intelligenti's answer too).

Comment: With the correction, Mathematica now computes: $$2 \left(4+4 \sqrt{2}-3 \pi \right) r^3.$$ This is the same result also found by @MathLover, hence there are good chances it is the right one...

Comment: @Intelligenti Yes it matches spot on :)